# Why some symbolic expressions don´t get simplified?

Tags: expression, sympy, physics, simplify, reducing

Hi I was working on a model for oscilation problems with Lagrangian mechanichs for my Classical Mechanics I course.

My problem is the following:

When I try to Simplify some expressions like the one in the image below, sympy just shows the division and doesn´t reduce the expression.

I was wondering whether this is some kind of limitation of SymPy (probably that´s not the case) or is just me missing something.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unhSS.png)

Comment: Could you add your example as reproducible code (as text, not as image)? That way, people trying to help you aren't obliged to type everything again.

Comment: As JohanC says, please post the code as formatted text. [See here for a post on why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [See here for details on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I'm new posting on programming forums so I didn't think about it. Thanks anyway I think someone may have found what I did wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

If SymPy doesn't know enough about the variables (like whether they are positive or zero) then it doesn't make a simplification. For `sqrt` you will get better results if you indicate that the variables are positive. Alternatively, you can use `posify` on the expression before attempting the simplification.

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> x,y = symbols('x y', positive=True)
>>> sqrt(x/y)/sqrt(y/x)
x/y
```

This would not be true if x were positive and y were negative (in which case the answer would be `-x/y`)

Comment: Wow I can't wait to try it. This must be what it's causing the error, it makes sense that sympy doesn't just simplify it. Thanks !!!